Python NLTK recognizing last name as ORGANISATION if name comes first in sentence
I am using Python's nltk library to extract names from a sentence. I am expecting output as ['Barack Obama', 'Michelle Obama'] but I am getting ['Barack', 'Michelle Obama']. My example code is as follows.
When I tried printing the ner_tree, I come to know that it recognise the last name Obama as Organization name.
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
 
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('maxent_ne_chunker')
nltk.download('words')

sentence = "Barack Obama and Michelle Obama visited New York last week"
 
words = word_tokenize(sentence)

tagged_words = pos_tag(words)

ner_tree = ne_chunk(tagged_words)

names = []
for subname in ner_tree:
    if isinstance(subname, nltk.Tree) and subname.label() == 'PERSON':
        name = " ".join(word for word, tag in subname)
        names.append(name)
 
print(names)

# Expected output: ['Barack Obama', 'Michelle Obama']
# Actual output: ['Barack', 'Michelle Obama']

The result of variable ner_tree is as follows:
(S
  (PERSON Barack/NNP)
  (ORGANIZATION Obama/NNP)
  and/CC
  (PERSON Michelle/NNP Obama/NNP)
  visited/VBD
  (GPE New/NNP York/NNP)
  last/JJ
  week/NN)

In above code, if the sentence is changed as follows then it will produce the expected output.
sentence = "As per our sources, Barack Obama and Michelle Obama visited New York last week"

The NLTK library that you are using have statistical model under the hood which is trained on huge data. And the model rely on context to understand the name, organisation, geography etc.
By adding the prefix words "As per the sources" the model get better context which increase the confidence score of the word "OBAMA" as Name.
These model do prediction based on the context word. With different context same word might have high confidence score for name compared to organisation.
To better understand the context thing, see below example:

sentence = "The official currency used in Barack Obama and Michelle
Obama visited New York last week."
Prefix word = "The official currency"

Now the word "Barack Obama" is tagged as Geography by the same code.
It happens because the context word around it make it look like Geographical thing.

As I already said, I noticed the same thing. But we don't have any control on input data. I come to know that, it might not be possible using NLTK library. I have to look for something else.
